# CORS header missing when project hosted in a Subpath

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have a Django(v2.2) project hosted on an url which looks like
`https://some.example.com/mypath/` which has an API endpoint at `blog/create`.
I need to make a POST request from `https://some.example.com/anotherpath/ofmine/` (using axios), but that gives me a 301 error with the following messages in Firefox 71.0:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://some.example.com/mypath/blog/create/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://some.example.com/mypath/blog/create/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

However, I **can** easily make the same requests to a dev server hosted locally.

Relevant settings:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_docs',
    'corsheaders',                                                          
    'django_extensions',
    ...
]

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/mypath'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

What could be the reason and possible workarounds for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. `some.example.com` redirects to `www.some.example.com` so I'd been trying to access APIs at `some.example.com` (which doesn't exist, hence the 301) from `www.some.example.com`. Prefixed the `www` on the request url and it's working fine; I don't even need CORS headers, of course.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) docs, you need to set the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to include your endpoint(s), or set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` to `True` to allow all hosts (not recommended for production though).

Comment: Yeah, already have that; forgot adding that part of the code here. Edited.